# Trouble accessing IIS hosted service on LAN

Tags: iis, hosting, lan

I have a web service hosted in IIS on port 87 (can't use default port for port forwarding with my ISP). I have it running under Default Web Site

I am able to access the web service on my local in IE without an issue, however, when I try to access it from other machines on my LAN, it does not resolve.

I edited the hosts file of my local to:

```
 127.0.0.1      testsite.local
```

In my bindings I have:

```
http       All Unassigned       Port:87          Host Name: testsite.local
http       192.168.1.111        Port:87          Host Name: <blank>
```

I also have my firewall turned off on the machine hosting for testing, still nothing. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, was because port 87 is considered unsafe. Switched it to 86 and it worked fine.